# Javascript: Elegant way to check if value is one of many constants

Tags: javascript

I have an object (intended to work as enum) like this:

```
var CardEnum =
{
    CA: 101,
    C2: 102,
    C3: 103,
    C4: 104,
    C5: 105,
    C6: 106,
    C7: 107,
    C8: 108,
    C9: 109,
    C10: 110,
    CJ: 111,
    CQ: 112,
    CK: 113,

    DA: 201,
    D2: 202,
    D3: 203,
    D4: 204,
    D5: 205,
    D6: 206,
    D7: 207,
    D8: 208,
    D9: 209,
    D10: 210,
    DJ: 211,
    DQ: 212,
    DK: 213,

    SA: 301,
    S2: 302,
    S3: 303,
    S4: 304,
    S5: 305,
    S6: 306,
    S7: 307,
    S8: 308,
    S9: 309,
    S10: 310,
    SJ: 311,
    SQ: 312,
    SK: 313,

    HA: 401,
    H2: 402,
    H3: 403,
    H4: 404,
    H5: 405,
    H6: 406,
    H7: 407,
    H8: 408,
    H9: 409,
    H10: 410,
    HJ: 411,
    HQ: 412,
    HK: 413
};
```

I have a function like this:

```
function myFunc(card)
{
    if (card == null)
    {
        // throw exception
    }

    // do something with card
}
```

I intend to use it like this:

```
myFunc(CardEnum.D7);
```

But how can I make sure that it throws exception if someone use it like this:

```
myFunc(170);
myFunc(103.5);
```

I have to check that the passed value is one of the key values of CardEnum object. Is there any elegant way to do that without iterating over all the keys of CardEnum object?

Just to be clear, this is OK:

```
myFunc(311);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If users can send _any_ data to that function, then they can remove any check you could add in that function, to validate the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your safest bet would be to change what you pass to the function.
Pass card names, instead of their values:

```
function myFunc(card) {
    if (!CardEnum[card]) {
        // throw exception
        throw new Error('Invalid card passed to myFunc!');
    }

    // do something with card
}
```

Instead of `myFunc(CardEnum.D7);`, you call `myFunc('D7');`

This way, users can't just pass arbitrary values to the functions. Instead, you *have* to pass a card name to the function, otherwise, it will throw an error.

If you *have* to allow `0` as value, this will work:

```
if (!CardEnum[card] != null) {
```

However, I'd advice against using `!= null`, because that also allows other falsy values to pass, like: `'', false, NaN.

This would be a safer alternative:

```
if (!CardEnum[card] && CardEnum[card] !== 0) {
```

Comment: Use `card in CardEnum` as `0`, `false` or any other false value will throw Error in this case

Comment: @Tushar: All _valid_ cards have a truthy value. No need for `in`. `CardEnum[card]` will only ever return either a card's number, or `undefined`.

Comment: For now, Yes! but in future when OP might want to add `0` then this will throw false error

Comment: Add more cards to a full deck? That's cheating.

Comment: Aah! Didn't realize those are cards. I think OP wants to check if the value `170` is present in the cards not the `key` from `myFunc(170);
myFunc(103.5);` examples, what you think.

Comment: Passing numbers that are not present I guess. The question is confusing with `keys`

Comment: `myFunc(CardEnum.D7);` also suggests that he is passing `value`

Comment: @sabithpocker: He is. And I'm telling him in my answer that there's a better way.

Comment: @Cerbrus var CardEnum = {TrollValue: 0, CA: 101, ......}; and I call myFunc('TrollValue'). I think it will throw exception?

Comment: In that specific case, yes, it will throw an error. If you _need_ `0` to be a accepted value, use: `if (!CardEnum[card] && CardEnum[card] !== 0) {`

Comment: Or you can change if (!CardEnum[card]) to if (CardEnum[card] == undefined/null).

Comment: No, but you can use `if (CardEnum[card] !== null && CardEnum[card] !== undefined)`. Note that I used `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Well, actually, `!= null` seems to work in this case

Comment: @Cerbrus In that case can you please update the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Object.hasOwnProperty()`

```
var CardEnum = function() {
  // object 
  this.card = {D7: 207};
  this.myFunction = function(prop) {
    // if `this.card` does not have property `prop`, 
    // passed as argument to `this.myFunction`,
    // throw error
    if (!this.card.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          throw new Error(prop + " not found")
    // else log `this.card[prop]` to `console`
    } else {
          console.log(this.card[prop])
    }
  };

};
// returns object containing `this.card` , `this.myFunction`
var card = new CardEnum();
// call `card.myFunction`
console.log(card.myFunction("D7"), card.myFunction("D123"))
```

```js
var CardEnum = function() {

  this.card = {
    CA: 101,
    C2: 102,
    C3: 103,
    C4: 104,
    C5: 105,
    C6: 106,
    C7: 107,
    C8: 108,
    C9: 109,
    C10: 110,
    CJ: 111,
    CQ: 112,
    CK: 113,

    DA: 201,
    D2: 202,
    D3: 203,
    D4: 204,
    D5: 205,
    D6: 206,
    D7: 207,
    D8: 208,
    D9: 209,
    D10: 210,
    DJ: 211,
    DQ: 212,
    DK: 213,
    SA: 301,
    S2: 302,
    S3: 303,
    S4: 304,
    S5: 305,
    S6: 306,
    S7: 307,
    S8: 308,
    S9: 309,
    S10: 310,
    SJ: 311,
    SQ: 312,
    SK: 313,
    HA: 401,
    H2: 402,
    H3: 403,
    H4: 404,
    H5: 405,
    H6: 406,
    H7: 407,
    H8: 408,
    H9: 409,
    H10: 410,
    HJ: 411,
    HQ: 412,
    HK: 413
  };

  this.myFunction = function(prop) {

    if (!this.card.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      throw new Error(prop + " not found")
    } else {
      console.log(this.card[prop])
    }
  };

};

var card = new CardEnum();

console.log(card.myFunction("D7"), card.myFunction("D123"))
```

Comment: Try actually explaining what's going on there. You changed a _lot_ of the OP's code without explaining what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var CardEnum =
{
    CA: 101,
    C2: 102,
//...
}

function isValidEnumValue(value){
return Object.values(CardEnum).includes(value);
}
```

Then :

```js
console.log(isValidEnumValue(CardEnum.CA)); // true
console.log("wrong value"); // false
```